# Сортировка в таблице с разным содержанием (текс, числа, смешанное содержание)

Tags: javascript

Делаю сортировку в таблице на js

Как сделать так что бы сортировалось в зависимости от содержимого, т.е. если текст то сортировка происходит по алфавиту как сейчас в первом столбце, если в столбце числа (с числами могут быть любые знаки и слова, например руб. % и т.д.) как во втором столбце, то сортировка идет по числовому порядку, а не лексикографическому, если содержание смешанное как в третьем столбце, то сортировка идет для чисел по числовому по возрастанию, а для слов по алфавиту.

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    // изменяем tHead
    let th = table.tHead;
    [...th.rows].forEach(row => { 
      [...row.cells].forEach((cell, index) => { 
          cell.classList.remove("asc");
          cell.classList.remove("desc");
          if (index === col){
             if(reverse) {
                cell.classList.add("desc");            
             } else {
                cell.classList.add("asc");            
             } 
          }  

        
      });
    });
    
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

```css
table {width: 100%;font: 12px arial; margin-top:30px}
th, td {min-width: 40px;text-align: center;}
th {font-weight: bold;}
thead th {cursor:pointer; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bork</td><td>1%</td><td>6-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yahoo</td><td>30%</td><td>А тут 30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td><td>5%</td><td>Здесь 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td><td>40%</td><td>50-60</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как-то так.

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    // изменяем tHead
    let th = table.tHead;
    [...th.rows].forEach(row => { 
      [...row.cells].forEach((cell, index) => { 
          cell.classList.remove("asc");
          cell.classList.remove("desc");
          if (index === col){
             if(reverse) {
                cell.classList.add("desc");            
             } else {
                cell.classList.add("asc");            
             } 
          }  

        
      });
    });
    
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(a.cells[col].textContent)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(b.cells[col].textContent))) {
          let aVal = parseFloat(a.cells[col].textContent);
          let bVal = parseFloat(b.cells[col].textContent);
          return reverse * (aVal - bVal);
               
        } else {
          return reverse * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
        }
        
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

```css
table {width: 100%;font: 12px arial; margin-top:30px}
th, td {min-width: 40px;text-align: center;}
th {font-weight: bold;}
thead th {cursor:pointer; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bork</td><td>1%</td><td>6-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yahoo</td><td>30%</td><td>А тут 30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td><td>5%</td><td>Здесь 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td><td>40%</td><td>50-60</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: обнаружил баг в скрипте, если в значениях писать не целые числа не совсем корректно сортирует http://joxi.ru/DrlB7ObUyjlMG2 и такой столбец тоже не совсем корректно сортирует http://joxi.ru/1A5GQ9XTb7Mowm https://jsfiddle.net/w8dsaq7h/1/

Comment: Не ну извращаться можно по разному. Я лишь показал как можно усложнить сортировку. А специфичные случаи нужно сравнивать дополнительно, благо вам известно что там может быть. Универсальных алгоритмов для вашей сортировки нет, нужно писать специфичные сравнения

Comment: нашел свою проблему)) если , заменить . то все сортируется корректно